# Which FLUSH command before taking EBS volume snapshot?

Tags: mariadb, aws

The `FLUSH TABLES WITH...` command has a few flavors. The [manual](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/flush/) meagerly describes the differences between:

- FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK
- FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK AND DISABLE CHECKPOINT
- FLUSH TABLES ... FOR EXPORT

Am I interpreting the manual correctly that if one needs to perform a **disk volume snapshot**, such as the [EBS Snapshot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSSnapshots.html), the preferred way now is to use the `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK AND DISABLE CHECKPOINT` right before initiating the snapshot?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why not take a dump of your MariaDB instance? With Percona's XtraBackup, you can even do it hot.

Comment: It's too slow and too heavy on local resources (CPU, disk) compared to a volume snapshot. I recommend this article as it's universally applicable: https://engineering.shopify.com/blogs/engineering/shopify-manages-petabyte-scale-mysql-backup-restore

Comment: I would play it safe -- shutdown mysqld.

Comment: Snapshots are checked offline for consistency, no need for any downtime, specially helpful if taken at 15-30 min intervals. They are practically "free" if done by the appliance like EBS. There are filesystem snapshots too, ZFS or LVM, but they consume resources of the host.